# Can we send sms from nativescript angular playgrond?

Tags: nativescript

I have tried to send an sms in background without any user interaction in vain. Is that possible in android for examle ?

Answer (score 1):

The project i am working on is to send sms bulk in background where input comes from a rest api. I gave a try to Nativescript but finally found out that going on native is more powerful and simpler.

For IOS... it is not our target in this project. We generally try our best not to develop anything for IOS. It is hell...no body likes hell i guess......may be daemins do :)

Thanks

Comment: Khalid, could you share part of the source code of the native app? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of {N} Playground is to quickly test / share your code without having to do the whole environment setup on your local machine, therefore it is packed / configured with only the mandatory dependencies / permissions required to do the job.

Sending SMS is not a common feature and requires additional setup & permissions. So it can't work with Playground.

Moreover sending SMS in background without user interaction is never supported in iOS, limitation set by Apple. On Android you might be able to do it by acquiring required permissions from user at run time.